# Close XLib application from another process

Tags: c, linux, signals, x11, xlib

I have a Xlib-based program with an event loop that uses `XNextEvent` to receive and process relevant events.

I would like to be able to gracefully close this program from another process (actually from a shell script). I need to do some cleanup when closing, so I considered to setup a signal handler (for example for SIGUSR1) and when this signal is received, do the appropriate cleanup.

My question is, how can I interrupt the (blocking) `XNextEvent` call from the signal handler?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Signals already interrupt the normal flow of the program. The system call inside `XNextEvent()` will be interrupted in order for your handler to run. You have nothing to do to achieve this.

Comment: I assume `XNextEvent()` will be interrupted for my handler to run, but once the handler is run, execution will resume and `XNextEvent()` will still be blocked. The question is how to (safely) unblock `XNextEvent()` from the signal handler.

Comment: I see. I imagine you do not want to `exit()` from the signal handler. I don't think `XCloseDisplay()` is safe to call from a signal handler either. Maybe setting a global boolean and injecting an event so `XNextEvent()` returns right away would be an option. I'll look around.

Comment: Unfortunately, after searching a bit, I don't think this can be done. No Xlib function is safe to call within a signal handler, and having `XNextEvent()` return after a signal is not possible unless you patch Xlib. Interesting material about this situation can be found [here](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/graphics/X/signals.html).

Comment: Very interesting read.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you for your comment and for the link, I think I found a way to solve this (see my answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do this based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592292/how-to-quit-the-blocking-of-xlibs-xnextevent) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889415/in-xlib-how-can-i-animate-until-an-event-occurs).

Basically you can use the `ConnectionNumber()` macro to get the fd that `XNextEvent()` is reading from. This lets me call [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) myself to wait for data on the Xlib fd *and* some other fd. Now it is `select()` that is blocking, and not `XNextEvent()`. I can easily unblock `select()` from my signal handler by writing to the second fd.

Pseudo-code for the event loop:

```
/* Get X11 fd */
x11_fd = ConnectionNumber(display);

while(1) {
    /* Create a File Description Set containing x11_fd and other_fd */
    FD_ZERO(&in_fds);
    FD_SET(x11_fd, &in_fds);
    FD_SET(other_fd, &in_fds);

    /* Wait for X Event or exit signal */
    ret = select(nfds, &in_fds, ...);
    if (FD_ISSET(other_fd, &in_fds) {
        /* Do any cleanup and exit */
    } else {
        while (XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAlready) > 0) {
            /* Process X events */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify this, the code you've provided is incomplete... Shouldn't nfds be replaced by x11_fd + 1? And why not use exceptfds?

Comment: As explicitly stated in the answer, this is **pseudo-code** showing how to solve the specific problem stated in the question; it is not meant to be a standalone example. Re. your questions: 1) nfds should be "the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the fd sets passed to select, plus 1". If x11_fd is the highest-numbered file descriptor, then you can replace nfds with x11_fd+1, otherwise not. It depends on your use case. 2) "Why not use exceptfds". Nobody says not to use it, it again depends on your use case.

Comment: I see, how do I create `other_fd`, and how do I unblock select by writing to `other_fd`?

Comment: Depends on your specific application and use case. Your other_fd could be stdin, it could be a pipe, it could be a network socket.. Better post a separate SO question explaining your actual problem.

Comment: The actual problem is exactly this post, it's 0% different... Is there some way of doing this where you can unblock select with other_fd for all *nix platforms? As far as I understand, `eventfd`s are Linux only...

Comment: If your question is "how do I create other_fd and how do I unblock select" then that is definitely a different question. Also: `select` (and its arguments) is part of POSIX, not Linux specific.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the process id, you can use the `kill` function:

[`int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html)

You can send any signal but `SIGKILL` (`SIGKILL` cannot be handled)

Comment: How can I (safely) unblock `XNextEvent()` from the signal handler?

Comment: Using [`XSendEvent()`](http://h50146.www5.hp.com/products/software/oe/tru64unix/manual/v51a_ref/HTML/MAN/MAN3/3363_X11.HTM) with a fake event?